# Webcomic that featured a "graveyard of gods"?

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I can't for the life of me remember the name of a particular webcomic that I saw last year. The story went something like this:

A young woman suddenly finds herself on an alien world which has hundreds of giant statues on it. The alien who is looking after her explains that they are the remains of the many thousands of gods that created the universe. All the aliens now living on that planet live and build around the statues, and I remember the artwork being really fantastic. Any ideas?

Additional:

I seem to remember it was quite short (at the time), only a couple dozen pages. Full colour, and in English.

Comment: Was it in English? Was it on Keenspot? How big was the webcomic? (like, multiple hundreds of strips or 10-20?)

Comment: Reminded me of this. .. http://www.provingthenegative.com/2008/02/dead-gods.html?m=1

Answer (score 12):

Sounds like [Kill Six Billion Demons](http://killsixbilliondemons.com/).

Here's the first page that properly shows the setting:

[image]

Later, the protagonist's guide describes the nature of their world:

> Throne is the kingdom of God. It is the center of the omniverse.
>  [...]
>  777,777 Gods, 777,777 Universes, Allison. And at the center, Throne, the ultimate Mausoleum.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a lot like [Dresden Codak](http://dresdencodak.com) (the main character is a young woman who frequently visits alien worlds, and the art is very good), but I can't find that particular story in the archive.

Comment: If it's Dresden Codak, it could be the one shot [Girl Vs Bear](http://dresdencodak.com/2006/07/24/girl-vs-bear/), where Kimiko travels to the "Forgotten Graveyard", which houses the ghosts of dead civilizations.